# How can I add a file management system to my website?

Tags: web-hosting

I've created a site in which I want to host user forums on the site.

I switched hosting to hosting24 due to their unlimited database feature.
However I there are some things that I have not quite figured out.

1. Is it better to display the forum as:
   MyFunForum.websitehost.com
   or
   Websitehost.com/boards/myfunforum
2. **How can I give admin file access to just a specific folder or file?** I basically want the user to be able to fully customize their forum, but I want to bar access to the main website.

I think number 2 is the main thing.
It doesn't really matter how the forum is displayed, I just want the user to have sole access to their forum only.

I realize a complete redesign of my site may be in order. Here is the site link:
[link](http://ttf6.com).

The initial premise was simple...maybe a little too simple. Now I'm sure I will need a content management system, but I want to know how to get it to work for the user first.

Thank you in advance for helping me with this.

Comment: Have you tried to create a ticket on the site?   I've found that you can limit access through FTP for a specific folder using the ftp protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cyber Sleuth for answering.
I feel that I have figured out the answer on my own. I believe.
I will need a good CMS system to do what I would like to do...I think.